# Recovering RAID 6: drives are ok, but partitions are "lost"

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, raid, mdadm

I faced strange issue with my RAID 6 array (8 HDDs, mdadm). Accidentially 3 drives were disappeared from it, with corresponding result - array has been ruined, but - all 8 drives are perfectly fine, no any errors in smartctl, no issues on partitions on them (/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1 and so on). The only thing I am confusing is that those 3 drives do not have msftdata flag on their partitions (sda, sde, sdh):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary

Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary  msftdata

Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary  msftdata

Disk /dev/sdd: 3001GB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary  msftdata

Disk /dev/sde: 3001GB                                 
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary

Disk /dev/sdf: 3001GB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary  msftdata

Disk /dev/sdg: 3001GB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary  msftdata

Disk /dev/sdh: 3001GB
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  3001GB  3001GB               primary
```

One more interesting thing - all partitions are accessible via Partition Wizard, and I was able to recover some data from the sda, sde, sdh (those without msftdata flag).

The question is - is it possible to recover partition structure using parted, fdisk, gpart, whatever, to assemble RAID 6 again?

Thank you.

Comment: In my experience, in this kind of situation, one must recover RAID from the backup media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to recover my RAID array. First, I replaced all SATA cables. Second - I checked all partitions:

> mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sda1 (sdb1, sdc1 etc)

confirmed that all partitions are mdadm-capable, checksums correct, have same magic number and then:

> mdadm /dev/md0 --assemble /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 .... -vf

And that's it. Array is clean, up & running.

Comment: Nice! Please *accept* the answer even though it is your own answer so people who search for this question can see someone solved it.